# Access main package from other package

Tags: go, import, package, program-entry-point

I want to access the main package from another package, but this is impossible because the main file isn't in a directory. I already tried putting the main file in a directory, but when I try to import it I get this error:
`import "../main" is a program, not an importable package`

The reason that I want this because I have a tcp server and a webserver that work together. The webserver can get the tcp server via the main package and the tcp server can get the webserver via the main package.

I already got it working with the webserver and tcpserver reading from each other(without the main package in the middle), but I want to keep some parts of the application at one place.

Is the the thing I want possible(Via the main package)? Or is it just stupid.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics, it sounds like you should have the webserver be under "package webserver" and the tcp server under "package tcpserver". You can then spin up a go program importing those two libraries. I do not believe you are able to import another package's "main" while you are inside "package main" already.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You cannot `import` the `main` package. Any shared code should go in a separate package, which can be imported by `main` (and other packages).

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-nuts/frh9zQPEjUk for discussion.

Comment: @Adrian What if you have something you need to initialize in `main`, such as a logger (https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#example-package-Presets)? You cannot have that in a utility package, for example, because you can't run `main()`.

Comment: Then `main` should pass it to the functions/methods it calls.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this is to pass a function call from the main  .
in which you create a `function` in your `tcp` or `webserver` then accepts a value in a function . then call it in the `main`

Because `golang main` is a `program`, not an importable `package`