# Workflow for Google Cloud Functions with Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When developing a small Google Cloud Function in Go. I noticed it will throw an error if you have everything in your `package main` - eg. `import "<whatever>" is a program, not an importable package`

So the solution is switch it out to its own package, then deploy. If something goes wrong, throw it back into a package main and work on it locally, then switch it back.

Is this the best workflow? The other option i see is possibly making the Cloud Function its own module and importing it into a main.go file.

Comment: Is the statement here is explanatory enough for not putting packages to be imported into `main` package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44421114/4636715

Comment: No, I understand that. The question is what's the best workflow for developing Cloud Functions on local

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create a `cli` folder in project's top level and then put `main.go` file using `package main` and `main()` function inside it. That allowed me to have separate file `cloud_functions.go` in root with different package name that has one or more google cloud functions in it.