# Importing "main" package as a library (According to _The Go Programming Language_)

Tags: go, import, package, program-entry-point

On page 308 of [*The Go Programming Language*](https://gopl.io), it says

> A package named main ordinarily produces an executable program, but it
> can be imported as a library too.

But when I try it, I get an error: `imp.go:5:5: import "foo" is a program, not an importable package`

So...what are they talking about? How can you import a main package as a library?

My trial code is just:

imp.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "foo"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(foo.Hi)
}
```

foo/foo.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

var Hi int = 3

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hi %d!\n", Hi)
}
```

Comment: great book, but the print version is 7 years old now and a lot has happened since it was published.  Looks like there's a 2 year old ebook - you should probably be reading that one instead, if you can get your hands on it

Comment: Also. Use modules. foo would be a stdlib package.

Comment: @DanielFarrell: I assume the corrections in later editions are the ones listed at http://www.gopl.io/errata.html, and there's nothing about this.

Comment: @Volker: Modules didn't seem to exist when _The Go Programming Language_ was written.

Comment: Modules _didn't_ exist when that book was written.  That's my point.  The book is increasingly inaccurate as the language changes below it.  The errata certainly doesn't represent all changes between 2015 Go and 2022 Go.

Comment: There have been practically no relevant _language_ changes, several _additions_ to the stdlib and lots of changes in tooling. The book is still a very good language reference. And it seem strange that someone still doesn’t know modules are a must in 2022.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relevant: [Access main package from other package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420826/access-main-package-from-other-package)

My best guess is that this was true when the book was written, but has since been made impossible. [golang/go#4210](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4210) is the relevant issue and it seems the change that stopped it from working landed in mid-2015 while the book was published only a few months after.

Comment: Thanks, that was informative. It seems that it does work in the specific circumstance of testing, which is probably what they meant (I added my own answer to that effect).

Answer (score 0):

It is true that go code can have a main and be imported as a package, but not the package containing the "main" function. What I suggest is to put all your business code in a separate package (e.g, in a sub-directory) and have the main package doing minimal things (initializing your app and blocking for instance). This way you can import any of your code's package, except main package.

However as a good practice, if you have a repository with a program which you want to import some code of, I'd suggest you to make a different repository for this code to make it an independent library.

Comment: You would think the creators of the language would be aware of such a limitation, wouldn't you? So if they say it is possible, you have to wonder what they mean.

Comment: Probably but this book is 7 years-old, golang has had many major changes since.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that it's possible to import the "main" package from a test for the same package.

With a file `foo/foo_test.go`:

```
package main_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "foo"
    "testing"
)

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println(main.Hi)
}
```

This works. Notice the import path "foo" results in a identifier `main`.

Since the statement appeared in the chapter on testing, they must have meant "it can be imported as a library too IN TESTS", but they left out that condition!

As far as I can tell, the situation when the book was published (Go version 1.5) was the same as it is now (Go version 1.17), since the [change 10925](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/10925/) referred to [by fstanis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815684/2132213).